# Script using find runs fine when I execute it, but does not run correctly from cron

Tags: scripts, cron, find

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in this script?

It is not working in `cron`, but works fine when I execute it normally.

**Warning: this command is dangerous and may delete lots of files**

```
#!/bin/bash

/bin/find  .  -maxdepth 1 -type d  -ctime +2 -exec /bin/rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Did you just delete every directory in your `$HOME` that is more than 2 days old ? Or have you been lucky and used `sudo crontab` ...

Comment: I think this question as it stands is **very dangerous** as other people might try if this works or why it doesn't work. DON'T TRY THIS AT HOME ...

Comment: I would suggest including what you are trying to do when you make a post like this. we can guess based on code but its better to say what you want it to do as well. Also you should way what it not working about it? does it do anything?

Comment: In Ubuntu, at least for me, `find` is in `/usr/bin/find` ...

Comment: I did something like this at work once on a production system. Took about 3 days to restore from tape backup. Lesson learned.

Comment: Since OP uses `/bin/find` in their question, the script wouldn't even work in the first place, so it's not as dangerous *to Ubuntu users* as is suggested, though admittedly in syntactically right form can be harmful. Now, the question is applicable enough to Ubuntu users, which again is baffling why people are voting to close this

Answer (score 8):

So let's see what you're doing here:

```
/bin/find  .  -maxdepth 1 -type d  -ctime +2 -exec /bin/rm -rf {} \;
```

Find all folders in the **current directory** (`.`) created more than 2 days ago and execute `rm -rf` on it.

The current working directory for a cronjob is the users home directory, for `root`/`sudo` cronjobs it is `/root`.

If you were really lucky, you used `sudo crontab`, and it did no harm, as `/root` directory is usually not used in Ubuntu.

If not, you basically deleted all directories older than 2 days in your home. This should be more or less anything of importance. `Desktop`, `Pictures`, `Documents`, `.config` ...

---

What you should do instead:

Use full paths:

```
/bin/find /path/to/my/folder -maxdepth 1 -type d  -ctime +2 -exec /bin/rm -rf {} \;
```

In any way

- be **very** careful with `rm -rf`, and do not use it unless you're 100% sure about it.
- have a backup ready.

Comment: Hi RoVo, thanks , i was skipping the absolute path i.e. ( /path/to/my/folder ).

Comment: Now the script is working fine.

Comment: Hello, @kmukeshk, if this answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) (by click on the grey tick ✓ left to it) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Comment: `/root` directory is usually not used in Ubuntu, that doesn't mean applications that aren't written properly won't try to install stuff into user's home directory. It's probably one of the cases where two wrongs (the command in question and weird applications I've mentioned) don't make one right

Answer (score 4):

This script depends on what the current working directory (`.`) is, which is probably different when you run it manually vs. when cron executes it.

Use an absolute path to the folder you want to work on there instead.

Comment: cronjobs usually run from the home directory as pwd. For `sudo crontab` that is `/root`.

Comment: i have checked using absolute path, but no luck also.